# jquery hasClass giving the wrong result

Tags: jquery, dom

I have used the hasClass method before but I have a scenario where is reporting as not been present although if I output the elements .html() it clearly shows the class is in use by *item* aswell as other classes.

The element that the class belongs too was dynamically written to the screen. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
$('.myList').each(function (index, item) {

    // Check marked as complete
    if (!$(item).hasClass('complete')) {
        // Not complete
        alert('not complete!' + $(item).html());

        completeFlag = false;
        return false;
    }

});
```

The html output:

```
<li id="myid" class="class1 class2 complete">some text</li>
```

Comment: could you show your dynamically generated html?

Comment: You've given no info from which to work. We don't see any markup or code which generates the item in question, nor are we shown any of the .html() output you mention. We see no context or execution order to be able to help you in any way.

Comment: *"Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?"* Yes: Not quoting the markup, or showing the `.html()` result you mention. `hasClass` works, so there's something specific in your situation that you misunderstand or which causes misbehavior, but we can't even begin to speculate on what it might be.

Comment: See the response by Mathias Bynens. I suspect that 'item' which is being passed to $() for the hasClass() check the the .html() call is a UL which contains the LI you added to your response. In that case, 'item' does not have the class, it's child element (an LI) does.

Comment: See my edit for clarity. Didn't think my question was so terrible to get 2 down votes albeit missing html() output. Hope it's clearer now though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you're checking the **list**, where you mean to be checking the list **items**.

Example of what I think you're doing:

HTML:

```
<ul class="myList">
  <li>This is not complete</li>
  <li>Nor this</li>
  <li class="class1 class2 complete">But this is</li>
  <li>And this isn't</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.myList').each(function (index, item) {

    // Check marked as complete
    if (!$(item).hasClass('complete')) {
        // Not complete
        display('Item not complete: ' + $(item).html());
    }
    else {
        // Is complete
        display('Item IS complete: ' + $(item).html());
    }

});
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/afebo4) (which doesn't work)

Here's how you'd check the **items**: Change

```
$('.myList').each(function (index, item) {
```

to:

```
$('.myList li').each(function (index, item) {
//         ^--- Note that we're now looping the
// list *items*, not the list
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/afebo4/2)

Comment: Noticed I was targeting the list class not the item. This is the answer with most effort so marked as the answer, Thank you. One of those silly errors that I was thinking too much about :)

Answer (score 2):

`.hasClass()` checks the specific element that matches your selector. You seem to be thinking it searches inside the element to see if the class is used there. That’s not how it works.

Comment: Absolutely correct. Showing $(item).html() only shows you the markup CONTAINED by the element, not the element's markup. In some browsers a property exists named outerHTML, which would show you the element in question. But .html() only returns the element's innerHTML value.

Answer (score 1):

Is it that one of the **child** elements in your html have the class but the actual item itself does not? I believe that `.hasClass()` only determines whether the actual element itself has the css class applied.